# Installing Skype error. What to do?

Tags: apt, skype

I'm in the process of installing Skype and this message just showed up:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install skype
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype : Depends: skype-bin but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What does that mean and what can I do???

Answer (score 0):

Try this to clear up the errors you're getting and install the older version.

```
$ sudo apt remove --purge skype
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt install skype
```

#### The latest version of Skype:

**Alternatively install the [Latest Skype from skype.com](https://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Skype-for-Linux-Alpha-and-calling-on-Chrome-amp-Chromebooks/td-p/4434299).**  It currently has more support from Microsoft (the new owners of Skype), as well as support for many features the older version doesn't have.

Installation is simple.  Grab the [skypeforlinux-64-alpha.deb](https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/downloading-web/?type=weblinux-deb) package.  Click on it and install from the software center.  Or via the commandline with:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i skypeforlinux-64-alpha.deb
```

Comment: I forgot to tell that I'm still running the Ubuntu 16.04 from a boot-able pen drive. I can not perform a lot of updates even the fact that I've reserved 4 GB of free space for use with the 32 GB pen drive for extra things as advised.

Comment: I'm triyng the second option suggested, to grabb the latest skype from skype.com. I've chose the first download option, the Alpha DEB. Lets see.